# Toggle property of an object in an array VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a user feedback form where users can rate the quality of the food item they ordered. I have an array `foodItems` which render the food list and i have certain reactions set up for the food items. I am trying to add a method so that user can provide the feedback but user can set up only one reaction at a time. So for instance for Pizza they can be `satisfied` or `dissatisfied` and the selected reaction should be highlighted and so on but i am not sure how i can do it.

Check out this sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/xxwMQJL?editors=1010).

Check out this working example:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      reaction: false,
      selectedReaction: "",
      foodItems: [{
          name: "Pizza",
          value: "pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Pasta",
          value: "pasta"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setReaction() {
      this.reaction = !this.reaction;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap justify-center>
        <v-flex xs6 v-for="(food,index) in foodItems" :key="index">
          <h1>{{ food.name }}</h1>
          <v-icon large left :color="reaction ? 'primary' : ''" @click="setReaction">sentiment_dissatisfied</v-icon>
          <v-icon large :color="reaction ? 'primary' : ''" @click="setReaction">sentiment_very_satisfied</v-icon>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

So basically i am trying to add the functionality for the users to rate the food. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The main concern is you need to have a reaction corresponding to each food item, so add a reaction/feedback property with each food item. Notice individual feedback change. There can be so many other approaches as well.

    https://codepen.io/pjain-techracers/pen/abvXPwK
```

Comment: Hope this works, it is the best approach to have reaction corresponding to each item

Comment: quick question. What if instead of assigning the `@click="food.reaction='good'"` and `@click="food.reaction='bad'"`inline, i want to assign it in a method call?

Comment: Surely you can do that, as you were initially calling function, the same way

Comment: Thanks, i like this way since i can track feedback for every object. Accepting as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are many approaches for this, but in the end what you need to do is, store rating for every food item.

What I have done in my implementation is created an array for ratings `selectedReaction`, which will store either `1, -1, undefined`. Whenever you add any rating, for any food, for the index of food in `foodItems` I add 1 for positive feedback, -1 for negative feedback at the same index in `selectedReaction`.

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
    <v-layout row wrap justify-center>
        <v-flex xs6 v-for="(food,index) in foodItems" :key="index">
        <h1>{{ food.name }}</h1>
        <v-icon large left :color="selectedReaction[index] === -1 ? 'primary' : ''" @click="setReaction(index, false)">sentiment_dissatisfied</v-icon>
        <v-icon large :color="selectedReaction[index] === 1 ? 'primary' : ''" @click="setReaction(index, true)">sentiment_very_satisfied</v-icon>  

        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
    return {
        selectedReaction: [],
        foodItems: [
        {
            name: "Pizza",
            value: "pizza"
        },
        {
            name: "Pasta",
            value: "pasta"
        }
        ]
    };
    },
    methods: {
    setReaction(index, isSatisfied) {
        const reaction = [...this.selectedReaction];
        reaction[index] = isSatisfied ? 1 : -1;
        this.selectedReaction = reaction;
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do is using a boolean value like `isSatisfied` which is false if user dissatisfiedm true if it is satisfied and undefined if no information has been given.

the problem with this is that if you write `if(isSatisfied)` and the flag is undefined, codeflow goes to else block. so you should write something like

```js
if(isSatisfied)
     //satisfied
if(isSatisfied === false)
     //unsatisfied
```

Another option is to use a string, you can store a string `feedback` that can be `undefined`, `'satisfied'` or `'unsatisfied'`.

You can do the same using a number.

Those last options are more flexible as you can "upgrade" feedback system without changing the model (obviously within certain limits).

That flags/strings/numbers must be stored somewhere. You could create a new feedback array of objects, each of them containing:

- food reference
- user reference
- user rating